# solving population size with exponential functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Problem: A species of fish was added to a lake. The population size ($P(t)$) of this species can be modeled by the following function, where t is the number of years from the time the species was added to the lake.
>   $$P(t)=\frac{2500}{1+4e^{-0.1t}}$$
>   Find the initial population size of the species and the population size after 
>   $8$ years.

My work:

after 8 years:

\begin{align}P(8)&= \frac{2500}{1+4e^{-0.1(8)}}\\
&=\frac{2500e^{0.8}}{e^{0.8} +4}\\
&=894 
\end{align}

initial:

$$P(0)= \frac{2500}{1+4e^{-0.1(0)}}$$

This is where I am stuck..

What is the next step that I need?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Did you mean to write $P(t) = \frac{2500}{1 + 4e^{-0.1t}}$?

Comment: May I ask why people are so quick to downvote?

Answer (score 1):

$$P(0) = \frac{2500}{1+4e^{-(0.1)0}}=\frac{2500}{1+4e^{0}}=\frac{2500}{1+4}=500$$